# IE 10 innerHTML Not enough storage is available to complete this operation

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer, dom

Our application is trying to embed all images in html using base64 (i.e. setting image src to data:image/png;base64,.....)

Our application will insert/retrieve these base64 embedded images to/from the dom tree dynamically. We found that when the size of the whole Html is around or greater than 3MB, if we try to insert/retrieve them to/from dom using jquery.html(), IE will throw exception "**Not enough storage is available to complete this operation**" around elem.innerHTML in jquery library.

When we use debugger to check the dom element, we found that the innerHTML, outerHTML etc will show "**Not enough storage is available to complete this operation**"

We have checked that there is no such problem in Chrome and Firefox. Is there any length limit of innerHTML in IE?

Comment: Did you find a resolution?